# Best way to iterate and remove items from an array silmultaneously

Tags: python

I have an array that looks like so:

```
data = [{'title':'10'},{'title':'15'},{'title':'25'},{'title':'6'},{'title':'4'}]
```

I want to iterate through the array while simultaneously removing elements that meet a certain criteria.

```
for element in data:
    if element['title'] > 10:
    # remove element from the array
```

Whats the best way to do this in python?

Answer (score 2):

```
data = [{'title':'10'},{'title':'15'},{'title':'25'},{'title':'6'},{'title':'4'}]
```

Using `filter`

```
>>> filter(lambda i : int(i['title']) <= 10, data)
[{'title': '10'}, {'title': '6'}, {'title': '4'}]
```

Using a list comprehension

```
>>> [i for i in data if int(i['title']) <= 10]
[{'title': '10'}, {'title': '6'}, {'title': '4'}]
```

Comment: He wants to *remove* elements whose 'title' attribute is greater than 10.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it. Notice the `[:]`

```
for element in list[:]:
       if element['title'] > 10:
          list.remove(element)
```